# Changing the style of the 'include_blank' text using a rails collection_select form helper

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, simple-form

I have the following `collection_select` field in a form, and I would like the 'Select a Garage' text to be gray (#555555) like the placeholder text for my other fields. How can I change this?

```
<%= collection_select :car, :garage_id, @garages.order('name ASC'), :id, :name, {include_blank: 'Select a Garage'}, { :multiple => false, class: "form-control garage-select" } %>
```

I am using Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.1.4, as well as the simple_form gem. Thanks!

Comment: What's the ID of the `select`?

Comment: I didn't give it one, but it has the class `.garage-select`

Answer (score 1):

You can style the first option of the select box in your CSS.

```
select.garage-select > option:nth-child(1) {
  color:#555;
}
```

**EDIT**

The browser default styling cannot be overwritten. You will need a library that can generate a CSS based select box.  Take a look at [this](https://select2.github.io/examples.html).

Comment: Thanks! This isn't working. When I inspect the element (the first option within the select field) the class is there and it's showing `color: #555555 !important;`, but it is not actually making the text gray. Any suggestions?